# Unable to Fix a Linker Error in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors

I am working on a project which is very new to me. I have a very basic knowledge of C++ and I am just unable to fix a linker error that I am getting while trying to build the project in VC++. Following is the error and definitions of 2 classes involved.

```
1>Dlg_Container_View.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CPictureCtrl::~CPictureCtrl(void)" (??1CPictureCtrl@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0CDlg_Container_View@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z$0
1>Dlg_Container_View.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CPictureCtrl::CPictureCtrl(void)" (??0CPictureCtrl@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CDlg_Container_View::CDlg_Container_View(class CWnd *)" (??0CDlg_Container_View@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z)
1>Dlg_Container_View.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CPictureCtrl::Load(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > &)" (?Load@CPictureCtrl@@QAEHAAV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall CDlg_Container_View::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@CDlg_Container_View@@MAEHXZ)
1>.\Debug/EDiscovery.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

The following are the class definitions (which I think are relevant. I have just copy pasted the complete defintion which might be irrelevant but I didnt want to miss out on anything). Sorry for this basic question.

```
class CPictureCtrl :
    public CStatic
{
public:

    //Constructor
    CPictureCtrl(void);

    //Destructor
    ~CPictureCtrl(void);

public:

    //Loads an image from a file
    BOOL LoadFromFile(CString &szFilePath);

    //Loads an image from an IStream interface
    BOOL LoadFromStream(IStream* piStream);

    //Loads an image from a byte stream;
    BOOL LoadFromStream(BYTE* pData, size_t nSize);

    //Loads an image from a Resource
//  BOOL LoadFromResource(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpName, LPCTSTR lpType);

    //Overload - Single load function
    BOOL Load(CString &szFilePath);
    BOOL Load(IStream* piStream);
    BOOL Load(BYTE* pData, size_t nSize);
//  BOOL Load(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpName, LPCTSTR lpType);

    //Frees the image data
    void FreeData();

protected:
    virtual void PreSubclassWindow();

    //Draws the Control
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);
    virtual BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);



private:

    //Internal image stream buffer
    IStream* m_pStream;

    //Control flag if a pic is loaded
    BOOL m_bIsPicLoaded;

    //GDI Plus Token
    ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
};
```

The above class is defined in the header file PictureCtrl.h which is included in the file where the following class is defined. Following is the class that has an object of above class as a member variable:

```
class CDlg_Container_View : public CDialog , public CParentIView
{
// Construction
public:
    CDlg_Container_View(CWnd* pParent = NULL); 
    ~CDlg_Container_View();
    CDialog * GetDialog(const int idx);
    void ClosePages();
    virtual void SetCurSel(const int idx);
    void AddPage(const char * cText, CDialog * pDlg, const UINT id);
    CPtrArray pPages;
    CStringArray csText;
    CUIntArray csIds;// standard constructor
    int iCurIdx;
    CString csTitle;
    virtual void Show_Dialog();
    virtual void Hide_Dialog();
    virtual void RegisterChildToParent(CString,CIView*);
    virtual void ChangeBtnState(CString p_strBtnName,BOOL flag);
    void SetControlText();
    void ResetDialog();
    void ShowMessageBox(CString msg);
    void EnableProject(bool p_blFlag);
    CFont m_StaticFont;

//  virtual void fun();

    // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CDlg_Container_View)
    enum { IDD = IDD_DLG_CONTAINER_VIEW_DIALOG };
    CRichEditCtrl   m_REdit_DisplayProjectNots;
    CRichEditCtrl   m_REdit_AddProjectNotes;
    CButton m_Grp_Bx_Project_Notes;
    CButton m_btn_Report;
    CButton m_btn_Export;
    CButton m_btn_Error;
    CStatic m_Lbl_Token_Balance;
    CButton m_Btn_Add_Notes;
    CStatic m_Lbl_Project;
    CButton m_btn_Collect;
    CComboBox   m_Combo_Project_Name;
    CStatic wndFrame;
   CPictureCtrl m_picCtrl; 
    //CHyperLink    m_hyper_Manage_Tokens;
    CStatic m_hyper_Manage_Tokens;
    CHyperLink  m_WebIdHyperlink;
    //}}AFX_DATA


// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CDlg_Container_View)
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:
         CBrush m_brush; 
         HICON m_hIcon;
    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CDlg_Container_View)
    afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
//  afx_msg void OnBtnCollect();
    afx_msg void OnBtnReport();
    afx_msg void OnBtnExport();
    afx_msg void OnBtnClose();
//  afx_msg void OnSelendokCOMBOProjectName();
    afx_msg void OnBtnError();
    afx_msg void OnBtnAddNotes();
    afx_msg void OnEditchangeCOMBOProjectName();
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    CDlg_Container_Presenter *m_objCDlg_Container_Presenter;
    BOOL m_blFirstTime_Collect;
    BOOL m_blEnableButtons;
    CString m_strProjectNote;
    bool m_blFirsttime_Project;


    //bool m_bAutoComplete;
    CString m_sTypedText;

    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);

    afx_msg void OnEnSetfocusReditDisplayprojectnotes();
//  afx_msg void OnCbnDropdownComboProjectName();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedCheck1();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedCheck2();
//  afx_msg void OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);
//  afx_msg void OnSysKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);
//  afx_msg void OnCbnSetfocusComboProjectName();
//  afx_msg void OnCbnEditupdateComboProjectName();

    afx_msg void OnCbnEditupdateComboProjectName();
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelchangeComboProjectName();
    //afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnProjectEdit();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnProjectEdit();
//  afx_msg void OnCbnCloseupComboProjectName();
//  afx_msg void OnCbnCloseupComboProjectName();
    afx_msg void OnCbnCloseupComboProjectName();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnCollect();
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelendokComboProjectName();
    CButton m_btn_Update_Project;
    afx_msg void OnCbnDropdownComboProjectName();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
    afx_msg void OnStnClickedLblManageTokens();
    void UpdateTokenCount();
    CPictureCtrl m_LogoPic;
};
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Those linker errors mean that you have not provided the definition of those three functions.
i.e constructor, destructor and Load function...

```
CPictureCtrl(void);
~CPictureCtrl(void);
BOOL Load(CString &szFilePath);
```

Comment: @labyrinth Make sure that you include CPictureCtrl definition (cpp) file in the build.

Comment: So I have to provide definitions of these functions in the class CPictureCtrl? But I can see these lines in that class. Ain't that sufficient?

Comment: @ravi It is provided in the post

Comment: @dmitri How do I check for that in the VC++ configuration? And won't the compilation fail before reaching the linker if the definition was not available?

Comment: No it's not I am asking for .cpp files coresponding to these .h

Comment: @labyrinth Include cpp file in the project. Something like File -> Add to project command or maybe drag and drop to the list of source files. I haven't been using VC++ for a long time.

Comment: @ravi Since I am new to project and exploring it on my own, I don't exactly know where can I find the implementation of the above classes. Can you help me with some tips on how to find that using VC++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include PictureCtrl.cpp in your project?

Comment: Yes I have PictureCtrl.cpp in the project which implements the functions discussed above. But from the header file, if say open definition/declaration (on right clicking thes functions) it does not take me to the .cpp file. But when I right click on this function in the .cpp file it takes me to the header file but also throws a dialogue box asking to resolve ambiguity. It shows 2 same files in that ambiguity dialogue box.

Comment: When I searched for the PictureCtrl.cpp in file explorer, I found the file. But I am not able to find it in the project hierarchy in visual studio. Any idea why could this be??